Open sets in $\mathbb{R}P^n$ or in any quotient space
Given the definition of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is the set of all dimension $1$ vector subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. The topology on this space is given by the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\}$ by the equivalence relation $x \sim \lambda x$ for all $\lambda \neq 0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\}$.
I was thinking about when $n=1$ and we have $\mathbb{R}P^n$ are just lines in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that passes through origin. And open sets in $\mathbb{R}P^n$ are generally sets that gets pulls to some open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$ by natural projection.
My question is that what does open sets in $\mathbb{R}P^n$ looks like? I am thinking any lines in it would be open? Since every element of $\mathbb{R}P^n$ can be pulled to a line in in $\mathbb{R}^2$ minus the origin, so the preimage is just a union of "open rays".
Also, I always have hard time thinking about open sets in quotient spaces in general. Whenever I think about quotient space I must go through the process of looking at its equivalent relation with the projection map. But sometime there are quotient spaces I hardly can recognize any open sets. Are there any good suggestions on how to think about quotient spaces and recognizing open sets in them intuitively?
Thanks

They locally look like usual open sets since it is a fibre bundle. Otherwise open sets are given by $\pi(U)$ where U is open and $\pi^{-1}(\pi(U)) = U$. You can use convenient representations with border at infinity if you want to be more at ease. Also in dimension one it is equivalent to a circle

If you have trouble finding such open sets, (in the setting where G acts on X) take any open set U and you get a « valid » open set $$ \Omega = \bigcup\limits_{g \in G} g \cdot U$$ and all of them are of this form. In this context just extend the open set you have radially

These are answers to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

You probably meant that elements of $\mathbb RP^n$ can be pulled back to lines in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ --- not $\mathbb R^2$ --- minus the origin. Also, open rays are, despite their name, not open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ when $n>1$.
